# Snake on python and pygame 3.2

Tags: python, pygame

I am currently in the process of coding a 3.2 python snake and under pygame, but I have a problem when my snake advance.
Head forward and not back, so it draws in some way.
Desolated if there are mistakes, I'm French.
Here is the source code:

```
import pygame, time

    from pygame.locals import *

    pygame.init()

    mur = pygame.image.load("carrenoir.jpg")

    a="mur"

    b="fond"

    c="serpent"

    fenetre = pygame.display.set_mode((900, 900))

    fond = pygame.image.load("carrenoir.jpg").convert()

    serpent = pygame.image.load("carrevert.jpg").convert()

    mur = pygame.image.load("carreblanc.jpg").convert()

    pomme = pygame.image.load("pomme.jpg").convert()



    t=[1]*21

    for i in range(0,21):

          t[i]=[1]*21

    for i in range(0,21):

          t[0][i]=a

          t[i][20]=a

          t[20][i]=a

          t[i][0]=a


    t[8][7]=c

    t[8][8]=c

    t[8][9]=c

    queue_i=8

    queue_j=9


    tete_i=8

    tete_j=7

    sens=1#1 haut2 droite 3 bas et 4 gauche

    for i in range(0,21):

          print(t[i])


    def affiche(t):

          for i in range(0,21):

                for j in range(0,21):

                      if t[i][j]=="mur":

                          fenetre.blit(mur, (40*i+40,40*j+40))

                      if t[i][j]=="fond":

                          fenetre.blit(fond, (40*i+40,40*j+40))

                      if t[i][j]=="serpent":

                          fenetre.blit(serpent, (40*i+40,40*j+40))

          pygame.display.flip()

    affiche(t)



    continuer = 1

    while continuer:

          for event in pygame.event.get():

                if event.type == QUIT:

                      continuer = 0

                if event.type == KEYDOWN:

                      if event.key == K_LEFT:

                            if sens==3:

                                  sens=4

                            elif sens==4:
                                  sens=4


                            elif sens==1:

                                  sens=4

                            elif sens==2:

                                  sens=2

                      if event.key == K_RIGHT:

                            if sens==3:

                                  sens=2

                            elif sens==4:

                                  sens=4

                            elif sens==1:

                                  sens=2

                            elif sens==2:

                                  sens=2

                      if event.key == K_UP:

                            if sens==3:

                                  sens=3

                            elif sens==4:

                                  sens=1

                            elif sens==1:

                                  sens=1
                            elif sens==2:

                                  sens=1

                      if event.key == K_DOWN:

                            if sens==1:

                                  sens=1

                            elif sens==3:

                                  sens=3

                            elif sens==4:

                                  sens=3

                            elif sens==2:

                                  sens=3

          if sens==4:


          if sens==3:

                tete_j=tete_j+1



          if sens==2:

                tete_i=tete_i+1

          if sens==1:

                tete_j=tete_j-1

          time.sleep(0.1)

          t[queue_i][queue_j]="fond"

          t[tete_i][tete_j]=c

          affiche(t)
    Some french word in english

    affiche=print


serpent=snake


tete=head
queue=tail

continuer=continue

fenêtre=window

mur=wall

fond=background
```

Comment: Make sure to use formatting tools to make your code read better.  Also, you don't need an empty line between each line of code!

Comment: Better now ? sorry i start on this website

Answer (score -2):

if sens==3:

```
                      sens=4

                elif sens==4:
                      sens=4


                elif sens==1:

                      sens=4

                elif sens==2:

                      sens=2
```

It's better to write:
if sens == 2 : sens = 2
else sens = 4

At first try to clarify those parts of the code, you should see it more clerly. Secondly, I think English won't understand clearly your problem.

Comment: En anglais, s'il-vous plaît

Comment: Sorry. That was my first answer I should read the terms first

Comment: I'm not a python expert and I actually can't run python on this comp. I just advise you to get a clearer code : that would be far better to work after. Moreover your problem isn't even explained clearly, according to me. Maybe am I not intelligent enough, but I don't understand what you complain about